# Ignore warnings in from Python modules (seaborn, sklearn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, warnings, seaborn

There are many questions related to the question title above and all basically tell you to do:

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

and to make sure this is placed **before** the first import.

However, even after doing this I get many warnings from `seaborn` and `sklearn`. I get `UserWarning`, `DataConversionWarning` and `RuntimeWarning` which, according to documentation, all inherit from `Warning` and should be covered by the above code.

Is there another way to hide those warnings?
(I cannot really solve most of them anyway)

**EDIT**

Example 1:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py:645: DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int32, int64 were all converted to float64 by StandardScaler.
  return self.partial_fit(X, y)
```

Example 2

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\distributions.py:340: UserWarning: Attempted to set non-positive bottom ylim on a log-scaled axis.
Invalid limit will be ignored.
  ax.set_ylim(0, auto=None)
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to show one or more examples where a warning passes through the filter, because the reasons may also differ from case to case.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest added the most common cases

Comment: If you put the filterwarning line *after* the import of seaborn, it works as expected, right? So possibly somewhere in the seaborn code, the warnings level is reset?!

Comment: Yes. Adding the `filterwarning` *after* the import works

Comment: So [this is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTRvG.png) a complete verifiable example of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example2**

It's a bit hard to track down; seaborn imports statsmodels. And in `statsmodels/tools/sm_exceptions.py` you find [this line](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/a8889192d705e86397acf1473fa3f4336b0b6816/statsmodels/tools/sm_exceptions.py#L125)

```
warnings.simplefilter('always', category=UserWarning)
```

in  which reverses any previous setting for user warnings.

A solution for now would be to remove that line or to set the warning state *after* the import of seaborn (and hence statsmodels). In a future version of statsmodels this will be fixed by [PR 4712](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/4712), so using the development version of statsmodels would also be an option.

**Example1**

I did not find a way to reproduce the first example from `sklearn`; so that may or may not have a different reason.

Comment: For now, as a workaround, I set warning state (before and) after importing these two libraries.